# Writing PictureBox image to disc via dialog

Tags: c#, picturebox, savefiledialog

I was wondering if someone can help me troubleshoot.

I'm new to programming and was looking to make my own photo viewer. I have it working great for the most part.

My issue is I wanted to be able to save the image I open into the viewer as a new image. I have some buttons to make changes to the picture. My problem is I have a save dialog that when done defining the save, and you press save, it just re-opens a new save dialog box and doesn't write to disc. My question is how can I actually write to file and prevent the save as showing up everytime I attempt to save using the dialog box?

Here is my code:

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Displays a SaveFile Dialog so the user can save the image
    //assigned to SaveAs tool strip
    SaveFileDialog savefiledialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    savefiledialog1.Filter = "Jpeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif|Png Image|*.png";
    savefiledialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    //if the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
    if (savefiledialog1.FileName != "")
    {
        //Saves the image via filestram created by Openfile method.
        System.IO.FileStream fs =
                (System.IO.FileStream)savefiledialog1.OpenFile();
        //Saves the image in the appropriate Imageformat based upon the
        //file type selected in the dialog box.
        //NOTE that the filterIndex property is one-based.
        switch(savefiledialog1.FilterIndex)
        {
            case 1 :
                this.saveAsToolStripMenuItem.Image.Save(fs,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                break;

            case 2:
                this.saveAsToolStripMenuItem.Image.Save(fs,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                break;

            case 3:
                this.saveAsToolStripMenuItem.Image.Save(fs,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                break;

            case 4:
                this.saveAsToolStripMenuItem.Image.Save(fs,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                break;
        }

        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to store the filename.  So next time you save, you already know where to put it.  Use a variable.

Comment: I'm new to programming, so if you have an example of what you mean, it speaks to me. @ bartoszKP, I'm using Visual Studio Express. The event handler is stored under "InitializeComponent()" which is properly attached to the form. This InitializeComponent() has the following code:

Comment: // saveFileDialog1
            // 
            this.saveFileDialog1.FileName = "untitled";
            this.saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All file" +
    "s (*.*)|*.* ";
            this.saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Libraries\\Pictures";
            this.saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save As";
            this.saveFileDialog1.FileOk += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.saveFileDialog1_FileOk);

Comment: You can edit your post. And please don't do that by destroying other people's edits, like before. Edit by puretppc was correct - you shouldn't use tags in titles.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm fully aware of what I can do. If you are not going to help me with my issue, please don't post anymore comments. I'm here to learn programming not to be affronted by about things I've done to make my post.

Comment: Seems you need to learn some basic culture before you'll learn programming. Not sure why you recognized my comment as an insult - it was just a tip on how things are being done here. Bear in mind that you're not only new to programming but also to this community. You're the one that should follow the standards established here. If you don't care about them nobody is forcing you to stay here.

Answer (score 0):

some where in your code you should have something like

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{

     List<someImageClass> images;// <------this here 
     /*someImageClass should store the paths to the images */

     string currentimage; //maintain this or if you are binding to listbox or other list control
                          //you will be able to use ((someImageClass) listcontrol.selectedItem).path



     private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

          //so in here you can
          if(!File.Exists(currentimage.path))
          {
              /*show dialog*/ 
              **EDIT** missed save via dialog part

              if(savelog.ShowDialog ?? false == true)
                {
                     //depends on how you are storing image data
                     // see below
                     imageclassinstance.save(savelog.FileName);
                }

          }
          else
          {
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(currentimage.path,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(bw))
                     {
                               bw.WriteByte();//loop this images are not 1 byte

                              /*you don't really need binarywriter it will depend on what you 

                               are using to store the image data. some types have 

                               built in save functions*/
                     }
           }
         .....
     }


}
```